# R6 Function in Function

Tags: r, r6

```
library(R6) 
pre <- R6Class("pre",

public = list(
    dbl = NULL,
initialize = function(){},
functionA = function(){},
functionB = function() {}
) )
```

---

Here is the code I want:

```
FunctionA ()
{
    FunctionB ()
}
```

But there is an error here.

> Error: could not find function "functionB"

Please let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
FunctionA = function()
{
  self$FunctionB ()
}
```

should do the trick. It is necessary to put `self` before the name of the memberfunction unless you make your class [non-portable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Portable.html). Here is a complete example

```
library(R6) 
pre <- R6Class(public = list(
  functionA = function(){self$functionB()},
  functionB = function(){"output from B"}
))

obj <- pre$new()
obj$functionA()
# "output from B"
obj$functionB()
# "output from B"
```